# I have an issue about cmake version

Tags: cmake

I want to update my Cmake to version 3.18.4 but my 'which cmake' is fixed to "/tools/Xilinx/Vitis/2020.1/tps/lnx64/cmake-3.3.2/bin/cmake" because I am currently using VIVADO and maybe it was fixed when i have installed it first..
I already installed my cmake-3.18.4 in /usr/local/ , also I can not remove cmake-3.3.2 because I am using vivado actively.. What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `/usr/local/bin` priority by add `/usr/local/bin` to your path after `/tools/Xilinx/Vitis/2020.1/tps/lnx64/cmake-3.3.2/bin`:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake
```

To make this permanent, add to the end (or right after sourcing Vivado scripts) of `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc`).

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I could solve it thank you. The problem was occured by a code source /tools/Xilinx in my ~/.bashrc